# Is it possible to communicate with a client without disconnecting in an asynchronous server socket using the Python asyncio library?

Tags: python, server, python-asyncio, protocols

The primary purpose of this project is for the server to store information about the client in a session upon receiving the client's initial request. The client then waits until the user inputs a command to be sent to the server. Once the command is entered, the server sends the command to the client, and the client responds with the execution result. Importantly, all these interactions take place while the socket connection is maintained.

I have used the asyncio library to convert a socket server written in Python to an asynchronous one. However, when the server is in a connected state with a client, it tends to ignore incoming requests from the client.

I also used the Wireshark program to inspect communication packets, and it's evident that the client did send the request. Additionally, when I examined the client requests received by the asynchronous socket in the server and printed them, the first connection displayed the request, but from the second request onwards, the client's requests were not being printed.

**The following code is part of the server code.**

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, *address: list) -> None:
        self.__STP = StoneTransferProtocol()
        self.struct = ConstructStone()
        self.__Server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__run_service_handle, daemon=True)
        self.__Command_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__run_command_handler, daemon=True)
        self.__address = address
        self.Sessions = set([])
        self.Session = None
        self.response = None
        self.command_list: dict = {
            "sessions" : self.__display_sessions, 
            "session"  : self.__display_session,
            "status"   : self.__display_server_status,
            }

    def run(self):
        self.__Server_thread.start()
        self.__Command_thread.start()
        self.__Server_thread.join()
        self.__Command_thread.join()
        
    def __run_service_handle(self):
        asyncio.run(self.__handle_Service())
        
    def __run_command_handler(self):
        asyncio.run(self.__handle_command())
            
    async def __handle_Service(self):
        self.server = await asyncio.start_server( self.__handle_client, *self.__address )   
        
        async with self.server:
            await self.server.serve_forever()
        
    async def __handle_client(self,reader, writer):
        packet = await self.__STP.AsyncReceiveStone(reader)
        self.Sessions.add( Session( writer.get_extra_info('peername'), reader, writer, packet ) )

    async def __handle_command(self):
        while True:
            cmd = input("Server: ")
            
            for command, function in self.command_list.items():
                if cmd == command:
                    print( function() )
                
            if cmd.startswith("set"):
                print( self.__set_command(cmd) )
                
            elif self.Session:
                await self.__client_command(cmd)
                
            elif await self.__shutdown_command( cmd ):
                break
            # else:
            #     print(f"\nCommand {cmd} not found\n")
            
        exit()
```

To address this issue, I attempted to implement the function handling the client's initial request using an asynchronous socket, while writing the real-time communication code with a regular socket. However, during the process of transitioning from an asynchronous socket to a regular socket, I encountered difficulty directly converting the asynchronous socket into a regular socket. Currently, I am trying to create a regular socket using the client address obtained from the asynchronous socket.